# CMake: gtkmm.h not found (only in header files)

Tags: c++, cmake, gtkmm

I currently develop a project using gtkmm-2.4 and cmake. I put the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-2.4)
include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTKMM_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_link_libraries(myapp ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

When I now include `<gtkmm.h>` in a `.cc` file, everything compiles just fine, but if I include a `.hh` file, then I geht the error

```
gtkmm_main_window.hh:3: Fehler: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? Please tell me if you need any additional informations!

Comment: Do `gtkmm.h` and your `.hh` file stay in the very same directory ?

Comment: what do you mean? `gtkmm.h` of course is in `/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/`